# VB Datagrid Disable AutoScrolling Focus on Selected column

Tags: vb.net, datagrid, scrollbar, autoscroll

Kinda new here but needed help and a good friend suggested this site.

My problem is I have a data grid in Visual Basic, it works fine but as the columns extend past the width of the window I needed a scroll bar. This is where the problem arose. When a column past the 4th is clicked the scrollbar will shift to give it focus. As there are check boxes here they are constantly clicked and when they are the scroll bar shifts but the button isn't checked and must be clicked again.

I was hoping there was a way to disable this Auto focus so clicking a column will not cause the scrollbar to move.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. ^__^

Answer (score 1):

There is no real autoscroll in vb, one of the sub method was causing it to jump by checking another cell off the screen then defaulting back to the one shown which had the appearance of a jump.